# Why is italic text not displayed in html files generated from Docbook/Oxygen

Tags: html, css, xml, docbook, oxygenxml

I'm using Oxygen Xml Editor 15 to generate Docbook Html, Docbook Webhelp and Docbook Pdf from a single Xml file in Docbook format. The pdf file is fine but the Html and webhelp files are not outputting the text I made italic as italic, text I made bold is shown as bold.

When I look at the html of the outputted data I can see Bold uses `<span class="italic">` and Italic uses `<span class="italic">` so both are using a similar mechanism, Webhelp references the stylesheet *oxygen-webhelp/resources/css/webhelp_topic.css* but I cant see a bold or an italic class within it. Html doesnt reference any stylesheet. Both files say they used *DocBook XSL Stylesheets V1.78.1*

How can I fix this so italics are shown, preferably by modifying a setting in Oxygen so I don't have to do it every time I regenerate the text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Need to add these two styles:

```
.bold {
    font-weight:bold;
}

.italic {
    font-style:italic;
}
```

to

OXYGEN_INSTALL_DIR\frameworks\docbook\xsl\com.oxygenxml.webhelp\oxygen-webhelp\resources\css\webhelp_topic.css